# Sequelize add a column that doesn't exist and throw and exception by it

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, sequelize-typescript

Im trying to do an insert to the next table

Posgrest table

[image: 1]

Im using (sequelize 6.13.0 ):

```
await Property.create(
                    {
                        clikalia_id: 1,
                        property_type_id: PROPERTY_TYPES.EDIFICIO,
                        street: newBuilding.street,
                        number: newBuilding.number,
                        zipcode: newBuilding.zipcode,
                        location: point,
                        owner_type: newBuilding.owner_type,
                        uv_crm_id: newBuilding.uv_crm_id,
                        easybroker_id: newBuilding.easybroker_id,
                        uv: newBuilding.uv,
                        stair: 0,
                        door: 0,
                        block: 0,
                        inner_number: 0,
                        floor: 0,
                    }
                );
```

but sequelize add a table named "building_building_id" and next it throw and exception because the table doesn't exist in database (if I reset the server It work and sequelize doesn't add the column but other cases it does )

I don't know how to avoid it and I don't want to reset the server always that it happend

any suggestion?

maybe Im defining my table building wronk ??

```
const Building = sequelizeSells.define(
    'building',
    {
        building_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: Property,
                key: 'id',
                deferrable: Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE,
            },
        },
        property_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: Property,
                key: 'id',
                deferrable: Deferrable.INITIALLY_IMMEDIATE,
            },
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
    }
);

export default Building;
```

---

```
const Property = sequelizeSells.define(
    'property',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },
        clikalia_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        property_type_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        street: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        number: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        stair: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        door: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        block: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        inner_number: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        uv: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        floor: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        location: {
            type: DataTypes.GEOGRAPHY,
        },
        zipcode: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        owner_type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        created_at: {
            type: DataTypes.TIME,
        },
        updated_at: {
            type: DataTypes.TIME,
        },
        uv_crm_id: {
            type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
        },
        easybroker_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false,
        createdAt: true,
        updatedAt: true,
    }
);

export default Property;
```

Comment: please show `Property` model definition

Comment: Done  
It error started suddenly, I don't know if maybe I have to clean cache or it is an error of my sequelize version... It didn't ocurre months ago

Comment: How do you create tables? By calling `sync`?